# Schema Using joigoose and mongoose for validation in node js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, joi

I am using `@hapi/joi` for validation in mongoose schema. I am converting joi object in mongoose schema using `joigoose` as follows :

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import joi from '@hapi/joi';
const joigoose = require('joigoose')(mongoose);
let objectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

let userInfo = joi.object().keys({
    userId: joi.string().required().alphanum().meta({ type: 'objectId' }),
    firstName: joi.string().required().min(4).max(20),
    lastName: joi.string(),
    birthDate: joi.date(),
    email: joi.string().email(),
    mobile: joi.number().max(10),
    isActive: joi.boolean()
})

let userInfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema(joigoose.convert(userInfo));
module.exports = mongoose.model('userInfoModel', userInfoSchema, 'userInfo');
```

This is throwing error as follows:

[image]

I am not able to figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Joigoose has fixed this error in 7.0.0 version: https://github.com/yoitsro/joigoose/issues/36

Run the command below to list all dependencies of packages in your project's folder

```
npm list
```

Find in the tree the joigoose and its dependencies:

```
+-- joigoose@6.2.0
| +-- @hapi/hoek@8.5.1 deduped
| `-- @hapi/joi@16.1.8 deduped
```

Install the same version of @hapi/joi, by doing:

```
npm install @hapi/joi@16.1.8
```

Unfortunately, until now, the latest version of joigoose is not compatible with @hapi/joi 17.x version.

Link: https://github.com/yoitsro/joigoose/issues

Comment: Thank you so much. Now its working fine after change the @hapi/joi version.